# save image to binary data of a ordered index

Tags: swift, core-data, indexing, append, binary-data

My swift code below is trying to to append the image that is in the pic image and save it into core data. The core data attributes are located in a image below. When the user enters 3 into the textfield the image the saved into core data should appear because that is the order in the index. 2 Images are saved when build so the new image should start at 3 on the index.

[image]

```
import UIKit
 import CoreData
   class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pic : UIImageView!
lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterT.delegate = self

    pic.backgroundColor = .cyan
    populateData()
}
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else { //here....
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return true
    }
    loadImage(at: index - 1 )
    return true
}




func loadImage(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            pic.image = UIImage(data: user.image!)
        } else {
            pic.image = nil
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}

@IBAction func add(){
      imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@IBAction func append(){

}

func populateData()
{
    let item = Users(context: context)
    let vex = UIImage(named: "on.jpg")!.pngData()
    item.image = vex
    item.idx = 0

    let item2 = Users(context: context)
    let vex2 = UIImage(named: "house.jpg")!.pngData()
    item2.image = vex2
    item2.idx = 1

    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed", error)
    }
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.

    pic.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Please check this for save and get image from coredata :- 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XQ3735PhiQ

Comment: @YogeshPatel your video I believe does not feature a core data index or at least how to append to that index.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method `populateData`, there is the code to create a record, to assign values to the attributes and to save the context.

If you want to add multiple images you have to calculate the next available index. The index is usually the number of saved items. If you have two predefined images at index `0` and `1` the next available index is `2`.

To get the number of saved records dynamically create a fetch request and call `count(for:` on the context

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
let nextAvailableIndex = try context.count(for: fetchRequest)
```

Comment: Where do I put this code? I tried putting it in func append.