# save image to a index ordered binary data attriubte

Tags: swift, core-data, indexing, uiimage, binary-data

My swift code below is trying to to append another image into a ordered binary data atribute. The core data attributes are located in a image below.  1 Image are saved when build so the new image should start at 2 on the index. In function append the user should be able to call image and appended to the 2 spot of the the index in a infite loop. So user enters 5 images. There will be 6 places on the index. https://github.com/redrock34/efef/upload.

[image]

```
import UIKit
  import CoreData
   class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet var enterT : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pic : UIImageView!
lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    enterT.delegate = self

    pic.backgroundColor = .cyan
    populateData()
}
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let text = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string), let index = Int(text) else { //here....
        // display an alert about invalid text
        return true
    }
    loadImage(at: index - 1 )
    return true
}




func loadImage(at index : Int) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idx == %d", Int32(index))
    do {
        if let user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            pic.image = UIImage(data: user.image!)
        } else {
            pic.image = nil
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch \(error) ")
    }
}

@IBAction func add(){
      imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@IBAction func append(){

}

func populateData()
{
    let item = Users(context: context)
    let vex = UIImage(named: "on.jpg")!.pngData()
    item.image = vex
    item.idx = 0

    let item2 = Users(context: context)
    let vex2 = UIImage(named: "house.jpg")!.pngData()
    item2.image = vex2
    item2.idx = 1

    print("Storing Data..")
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Storing data Failed", error)
    }
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")

    }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
    let nextAvailableIndex = try context.count(for: fetchRequest)
    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.

    pic.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}}
```

Comment: What is your question? Any error messages?

Comment: In func append. I want to save what is place on the imageview to the binary data ordered set. So right now in func populateData() that sets page 1. In func append it should set the 2 page or 2nd image based on what is placed in the imageview.

Comment: Don't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086549/save-image-to-binary-data-of-a-ordered-index). My answer in your previous question describes how to do it. It's pretty straightforward. Just create and save the record when the image  was chosen. Please learn (to understand) the stuff. It seems that you have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: @vadian you mean put those 2 lines of code in func imagePickerController?

Comment: Yes. After the image is chosen `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called so this is the preferred place. And it's more than the 2 lines of code as described in my answer.

Comment: I updated my code above with your suggeustions. I put your suggested two lines of code in func imagePickerController I guess I need a catch part if there is a try part. I am getting a compile error with the try part.

Comment: No you didn't. You have to create a new record with `Users(context: context)`, assign the image to the `pic` attribute and assign `nextAvailableIndex` to the `idx` property, then save the context. Regarding the compiler error: Look at the other occurrences of `try` and the code around it. Please (try to) learn something.

Comment: So when you say 'Create a new record' your talking about the first 4 lines in func populateData()